# Architecture choices for IOS group chat application

Tags: ios, mobile

I'm working on a IOS app that has a mode where updates are broadcast to a small group of users who are "online" - like a private chat room.  There may be thousands of these going on simultanenously with millions of update push items.  From an architecture point of view, am I better of:

1. creating a realtime chat server-side with websockets (or socket io)
   to notify the active clients
2. Should I use Apple notifications via private topic name
3. Some other notification service?

Comment: socket IO will suit for you based on your requirement

Comment: Apple push (remote) notifications are not guaranteed delivery.